# Install bootstrap v4-dev branch using jspm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jspm, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to install the [bootstrap v4-dev branch](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev) using jspm?

I've tried:

```
jspm install github:twbs/bootstrap@v4-dev
```

This kind of works, but the dist folder is empty.

I'm not sure if jspm supports installing branches in this manner.  The docs say:

> Any version tag or **branch** can be installed this way for GitHub and npm. Commit-based installs are not supported for the GitHub registry currently.
>
> https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Installing-Packages

---

## Edit

Tried:

```
jspm install github:twbs/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha
```

Same result- empty dist\css and dist\js folders.

[image: folders]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jspm install github:twbs/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha
```

You can install from any tag, you just have to use the name of the tag (minus the `v` in front):
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases

I believe that in order to get the whole `@3.5.0` thing to work the `v` in tags is stripped by JSPM when querying for available versions.  This means if you try to install `v4.0.0-alpha` you will get an error saying it isn't found.

On top of that, you will need an override since it would appear that JSPM can't figure it all out (it uses the package.json by default I believe).  You can see the override for 3.3.4 here: https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/twbs/bootstrap%403.3.4.json

If you are lucky, you can just copy that override.  If there are significant changes to the project structure in 4.0 then you will have to tweak the override a little.  You can do local overrides by following the instructions here https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#testing-configuration.  Coincidentally, bootstrap is what they use in the example.

Once you have it figured out, you can submit a PR to the JSPM Registry so others can benefit from your work.

Comment: Strange- this command had the same result as what I initially tried: subfolders under dist are empty...  They're not empty if you manually download the release from github.  Not sure why jspm would drop the contents of those folders.

Comment: It is because you need the override.  The JSPM registry has an override for 3.3.4 but not 4.0.0.  JSPM can auto import some libraries without help.  Bootstrap is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks- I created an override: https://github.com/jspm/registry/pull/534
I had contributed overrides in the past for breeze, etc.  I was confused because I hadn't seen jspm skip files when I *wasn't* using an override.  I wonder if there's a bug where it's using one of the v3 overrides when installing the v4 alpha.